How to stop Mac Safari from closing itself?
I'm running Sonoma on an M1 MacBook Air with the maximum 16gb RAM.
I always used to just use Chrome for browsing but a few months ago I switched to using Chrome for everything but YouTube, which I use with Safari.
I'm usually offline at home in the evenings but keep a bunch of YouTube tabs open in both browsers to read offline, or for the Safari YouTube ones, to resume watching the next day.
But recently I've noticed that most times when I reconnect to the Internet, Safari has closed itself without prompting me.
Most videos remember where they were paused but an annoying number reset to the beginning. If not for this I wouldn't mind it closing down.
I've looked in the Safari settings and there is nothing in "General" or "Advanced" and the other tabs don't seem relevant.
Is there a setting for this somewhere or generally some way to prevent it from happening?

Do you happen to have low disk space? My browsers(safari/chrome) have never closed themselves no matter how many tabs I have open. System should just swap them out to disk. (i also have 16G RAM)

@hym3242: I did when I started seeing this but I cleared up around 10gig and it still happened a few times. 7.5gig free at this moment.

I think that's too low for macOS to stop this aggressiveness. I think it is a good measure to keep a portion of storage free just to stop Apple devices evicting iCloud cache and silently killing apps. (That's why I always select the storage option above my anticipated usage!)

@hym3242 Hmm well that's quite unfortunate. There is no storage to put aside for more important programming-related stuff let alone for undocumented Apple silliness. I got the most extra storage I could afford and there are no upgrade path other than external drives. Oh well.

I've never heard of Safari closing itself, unless it's crashing. Have you checked crashlogs? So Safari is up and running; you turn on the WiFi, and poof, it quits..? If there are problems due to lack of disk space, then you should get an alert. (Don't all OSes require some free space?) The best advice is always "try it without Chrome", of course. ;-)

@benwiggy I've never caught it in the act of quitting. Just now I turned on the hotspot & Wi-Fi after waking up and Safari is still there but I had tabbed to it not long before. It seems to do it when Safari hasn't been touched at all for some time. I'll look into the crashlogs.

@benwiggy lots of crashes of bluetoothd recently and a couple each of dmd and rtcreportingd, but no mention of Safari in there.
